# Add reviews in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add reviews to my woo commerce products as an Admin. I want to add reviews that I can copy from another website and put those in mine for the same product.

Comment: Well, I don't understand. If you cannot reply to the questions or you have no idea about it, at least don't downvote it. Get a life!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really that hard, is it? You just have to edit the product and scroll down below it. You'll find "Reviews", where you can add one.
[image]

If this is not present, you will need to add it. On the top of the page where it says "Screen Options", make sure "Reviews" is checked.

Comment: Hi, @Reigel I need to add comments not as a single user but for many into my products.